# How to render HTML content which size can auto grow in WPF?

Tags: c#, html, wpf

I have a task to create a WPF view which contains both WPF content and HTML content. All the contents should act as one single page that can scroll together inside a `ScrollViewer`.

Outer XAML:

```
<UserControl ...
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             ...
             Background="White" MinWidth="1440" MinHeight="810">
    <DockPanel>
        <!-- Something else here -->
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Inner XAML:

```
<UserControl ...
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             ...
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- Something else here -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1380"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TabControl Grid.Column="1">
                <TabItem Header="Tab1" VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
                    <Frame Source="{Binding ...}" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Top"/>
                </TabItem>
                <!-- Something else here -->
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The problem is, HTML content never extends. Instead, `Frame` shows its own scroll bar. This is not acceptable.

I have tried `WebBrowser` control and `Frame` control, but nothing worked.

1. Is there any solution with native WPF control?
2. If not, can any other controls do this, such as WinForm WebBrowser or CefSharp?